# Kha'Zix's Q on hit proc

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Kha'Zix's Q proc on hit effects? If so, does it proc Feral Flare as well?
Does Farel Flare proc on on hit effects in the first place (Ezreal's Q etc)?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, the only abilities that apply on-hit effects are either Attack Enhancers (Wu's Crushing Blow, Nasus siphon strike comes to mind), or abilities that state that they actually do apply on-hit effects (parrley, mystic shot, etc). Any bonuses consider them as auto-attacks (with a few math tweaks here and there). So yeah, if an ability applies on-hits, it will say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kha'Zix Q is a normal single target spell which deals physical damage and it does **not** apply on-hit effects. It does however benefit from Spellvamp and It will also apply Rylais slow and the Muramana passive (bonus damage to toggle).

Feral flare will only proc with **Autoattacks or spells that apply on-hit effects** (Ezreal Q, GP Q, Yasuo Q etc) and not with other spells.

Also a spellshield will block all spells, including those applying on-hit effects.